# SharePoint 2010 Calculated FIeld - Getting a Substring out of a Field

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I need to find a way to get a portion from a field
called opportunity name into its own field called XID,

an example of an opportunity name is NETC-5000-2016-NG2580.

Start and end locations will not always be the same but the beginning would be -NG and the end would be the first space after that.

So in the case above NG2580

Not all Opportunity Names would have a -NG

And tried

```
=IF(
    ISERR(
          FIND( "-NG" ; [Opportunity Name] )
         )
    ;""
    ;MID(
         [Opportunity Name]
         ;FIND( "-NG" ; [Opportunity Name] )
         ;FIND(
               " "
               ;[Opportunity Name]&" "
               ;FIND( "-NG" ; [Opportunity Name] )
              )
               -FIND( "-NG" ; [Opportunity Name] )
        )
    )
```

Comment: I tried to be careful with adding spaces and linebreaks, did I delete that **)** after the FIND that looks for the space " "? Or is that the error you have in your Formula?

Comment: it just got a generic error when I tried to add to the calculated field and clicked ok...

maybe what would make it easier is the substring would start where -NG begins plus one and always go for 6 characters

Comment: Yea tried this and get an error

=IF(ISERR(FIND( "-NG" ; [Opportunity Name] ));"";MID([Opportunity Name];FIND( "-NG" ; [Opportunity Name] );FIND(" ";[Opportunity Name]&" ";FIND( "-NG" ; [Opportunity Name] ));FIND( "-NG" ; [Opportunity Name] ) ) )

The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula

```
=IF(ISERROR(MID(A4,SEARCH("-NG",A4,1)+1,SEARCH(" ",A4,SEARCH("-NG",A4))-SEARCH("-NG",A4)-1)),"",MID(A4,SEARCH("-NG",A4,1)+1,SEARCH(" ",A4,SEARCH("-NG",A4))-SEARCH("-NG",A4)-1))
```

Replace A4 by SharePoint column name - [Opportunity Name]

Comment: note: if you add a Tab or 4 spaces, Formulas in posts will be formatted as code and syntax highlighting will be applied

Comment: =RIGHT([Opportunity Name],LEN([Opportunity Name])-INT(FIND("-NG",[Opportunity Name])))

 Opportunity Name = PMNMCI-5000-2015-NG1270 - Tier 3 Field Service Support

 Result is - NG1270 - Tier 3 Field Service Support

 Now I need to figure out how to get on the 6 characters NG1270 

 AND when -NG does not exist I don't want #VALUE!

Comment: Try above updated formula